# How to highlight text in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

Basically I'm trying to change the color and style of certain Wordpress authors by name.

If a post is posted by JohnMclaren, Wordpress would identify the text and the authors name would be green and bolded.

If other author name - no style applied.

Basically I want to highlight my name among other authors, when the post is published.

Any help would be appreaciated.
Thanks.

Comment: You could get an array of all the author link elements with JavaScript and add a style to the nodes that contain that author name. It's hard to give exact code without seeing your site. Can you use chrome developer tool Ctrl+Shift+i, Inspector (Ctrl+Shift+C) and hover over your author name. Then in the elements pane, highlight the code for your author name, right-click > copy > Copy JS Path and paste that here.

Comment: Thanks for your effort, found the simple solution. Added as an answer for everyone else to use.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the working solution:

```
<?php if (get_the_author_meta('display_name') === 'daveMClaren') {
echo '"<b><a href='https://www.mywebsite.com/author/" . esc_attr(get_the_author()) . "'>" . esc_html(get_the_author()) . "</a></b>";
} else {
echo get_the_author();
} ?>
```